# Zeitwerk: Add engine/gem directories to autoload path of parent Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zeitwerk

I'm trying to switch to Zeitwerk in an existing, older Gem (Rails::Engine). Until now all files have been manually `require`d and `autoload`ed. Plus the engine's lib-folder was added to autoload_paths via `config.autoload_paths += paths["lib"].to_a` in `class MyEngine < Rails::Engine` .

The switch to use Zeitwerk worked fine via the described way on the [Readme](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#synopsis):

```
require "zeitwerk"
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.for_gem
.
. --> more project specific stuff here
.
loader.setup # ready!
```

So far so good! Now I want to use the Gem in a Rails app and add the engine's directories to the autoload_path of the Rails application. This worked fine previously via the above mentioned `config.autoload_paths`. If I do this now, it fails with the following error message:

```
Zeitwerk::Error:
  loader

#<Zeitwerk::Loader:0x00000001094d4bd0
...

wants to manage directory /gems/<NameOfGem>/lib, which is already managed by

#<Zeitwerk::Loader:0x0000000106b2d728
...
```

What is the correct way to add the engine's lib-directories to the autoload path of the Rails application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Rails* sets up two loaders `main` and `once`:

```rb
Rails.autoloaders.main
Rails.autoloaders.once
```

These are just instances of `Zeitwerk::Loader`. *Rails* also gives you a config to add root directories to these loaders:

```rb
config.autoload_paths         # main
config.autoload_once_paths    # once
```

When gem's `lib` directory is added to autoload through one of these configs, *lib* becomes a root directory:

```rb
# config.autoload_paths += paths["lib"].to_a

>> Rails.autoloaders.main.root_dirs
=> 
...                    
 "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/my_engine/lib"=>Object,
...
```

When a class from the gem is called, *zeitwerk* uses registered loaders to look up and to load the file corresponding to this class.

If the gem then sets up its own loader:

```
require "zeitwerk"
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.for_gem
loader.setup
```

another instance of `Zeitwerk::Loader` is created with its own root directories:

```
>> Zeitwerk::Registry.loaders.detect { |z| z.tag == "my_engine" }
=> 
#<Zeitwerk::GemLoader:0x00007fe5e53e0f80
...
 @root_dirs={"/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/my_engine/lib"=>Object},
...

# NOTE: these are the two loaders registered by rails
>> Zeitwerk::Registry.loaders.select { |z| z.tag =~ /rails/ }.count
=> 2
```

*Zeitwerk* doesn't allow two loaders to have a shared directory and raises an error showing two conflicting loaders.

Because the gem is a *Rails::Engine* the best option is to let *rails* manage *zeitwerk* loaders and remove *Zeitwerk::Loader.for_gem* setup.

```
# only use rails config
config.autoload_paths += paths["lib"].to_a
```

On the other hand, gem loader is already set up and *config.autoload_paths* is not needed.

```rb
# NOTE: without any loaders
>> MyEngine::Test
# (irb):1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant MyEngine::Test (NameError)                                            
# MyEngine::Test                                
#         ^^^^^^

# NOTE: with gem loader
#
#   require "zeitwerk"
#   loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.for_gem
#   loader.setup                           
#
>> MyEngine::Test
=> MyEngine::Test

# NOTE: with rails `main` loader
#
#   config.autoload_paths += paths["lib"].to_a
#
>> MyEngine::Test
=> MyEngine::Test

# NOTE: with gem loader and rails loader
$ bin/rails c
# /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.0/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:480:in
# `block (3 levels) in raise_if_conflicting_directory':
# loader (Zeitwerk::Error)
```

**Update**

```
# Use rails loaders
# config.autoload_path          .->  Zeitwerk::Loader(@tag=rails.main)
# config.autoload_once_path     |->  Zeitwerk::Loader(@tag=rails.once)
#                               |
# Or create a new loader        |
# Zeitwerk::Loader.for_gem      |->  Zeitwerk::GemLoader(@tag=my_engine)
#                               |
# my_engine/lib can only be in one of these
```

*Zeitwerk* does the loading and reloading. *Rails* is just another gem here.

If you don't use rails config, *Zeitwerk* will find files through `Zeitwerk::GemLoader(@tag=my_engine)`, that the gem has created.

If you use rails config, *Zeitwerk* will find files through `Zeitwerk::Loader(@tag=rails.main)`, that rails has created (making *GemLoader* unnecessary).

If *lib* is a root directory in any of the existing loaders there is no need to have any requires or autoloads for files in *lib* directory. Except for things that are needed before *Zeitwerk* kicks in, like *MyEngine::Engine* from *lib/my_engine/engine.rb*.

Comment: That was an excellent answer .

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So if I wanna get rid of all the requires (and what not) in the Engine and use Zeitwerk as a file loader, I cannot use `config.autoload_paths += paths["lib"].to_a` any longer. But it's not necessary, as the Zeitwerk::Loader from the main Rails app will find the files from the Engine anyway. Correct? Or I just keep everything as it is (with requires, autoloads, ...) and use `config.autoload_paths`.